# According to the Bible where exactly did God create Adam?

Tags: biblical-basis, scriptures, adam, eden

Where did God create Adam according to scripture?

Is this in the garden or somewhere else according to scripture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Where was Adam created, according to the Scriptures?**

In the Book of Geneses, we can find a little indication as to where Adam was created.

> 7then the Lord God formed the man of dust from the ground and breathed into his nostrils the breath of life, and the man became a living creature. 8**And the Lord God planted a garden in Eden, in the east, and there he put the man whom he had formed.** [Geneses 2:7-8 (ESV)](https://www.esv.org/Genesis+2/)

In the visions of Anne Catherine Emmerich we can see that she believed that Adam was created not in the Earthly Paradise, but in the region in which Jerusalem.

> [3. **Adam and Eve**](https://tandfspi.org/ACE_vol_01/ACE_1_0001_out.html)
>
> I saw Adam created, not in Paradise, but in the region in which Jerusalem was subsequently situ­ated. I saw him come forth glittering and white from a mound of yellow earth, as if out of a mold. The sun was shining and I thought (I was only a child when I saw it) that the sunbeams drew Adam out of the hillock. He was, as it were, born of the virgin earth. God blessed the earth, and it became his mother. He did not instantly step forth from the earth. Some time elapsed before his appearance. He lay in the hillock on his left side, his arm thrownover his head, a light vapor covering him as with a veil. I saw a figure in his right side, and I became conscious that it was Eve, and that she would be drawn from him in Paradise by God. God called him. The hillock opened, and Adam stepped gently forth. There were no trees around, only little flowers. I had seen the animals also, coming forth from the earth in pure singleness, the females separate from the males.
>
> And now I saw Adam borne up on high to a gar­den, to Paradise.
>
> God led all the animals before him in Paradise, and he named them. They followed him and gam­boled around him, for all things served him before he sinned. All that he named, afterward followed him to earth. Eve had not yet been formed from him.
>
> I saw Adam in Paradise among the plants and flowers, and not far from the fountain that played in its center. He was awaking, as if from sleep. Although his person was more like to flesh than to spirit, yet he was dazzlingly white. He wondered at nothing, nor was he astonished at his own existence. He went around among the trees and the animals, as if he were used to them all, like a man inspecting his fields.
>
> Near the tree by the water arose a hill. On it I saw Adam reclining on his left side, his left hand under his cheek. God sent a deep sleep on him and he was rapt in vision. Then from his right side, from the same place in which the side of Jesus was opened by the lance, God drew Eve. I saw her small and del­icate. But she quickly increased in size until full grown. She was exquisitely beautiful. Were it not for the Fall, all would be born in the same way, in tran­quil slumber.
>
> The hill opened, and at Adam's side arose a crys­talline rock, formed apparently of precious stones. At Eve's, lay a white valley covered with something like fine white pollen.

Lambert Dolphin writes that Adam after he was created was placed in the Garden which lay to the East. Because of this statement Jewish sages have long claimed that Adam was created in what is now the land of Israel.

> [**Earliest Legends about the Promised Land**](http://www.templemount.org/earlytm.html)
>
> No one knows exactly where the Garden of Eden described in the Bible was located. The general area is generally thought to be in the Tigris-Euphrates Valleys. Sedimentary deposits from the flood of Noah are thousands of feet deep now in the entire area, so the "ruins" of the Garden of Eden are not likely to turn up by accident.
>
> However, Adam after he was created was placed in the Garden which lay to the East. Because of this statement Jewish sages have long claimed that Adam was created in what is now the land of Israel. Adam's footprint in stone is said by Muslim guides to still exist in the bedrock of the Macpelah in Hebron. Early Jewish legends state that Adam himself was buried in the Cave Abraham later purchased for burying his wife.
>
> On Mt. Moriah, the present-day Temple Mount in Jerusalem the exposed bedrock under the Dome of the Rock is known as "the Foundation Stone"in Hebrew Even ha-Shetiyah. Although the Jewish Temples were later built on the same foundation stone, or an extension of this same bedrock elsewhere on Mt. Moriah, the term "foundation stone" refers to the creation of the earth by God on the First Day.
>
> > And it was called the Foundation Stone because the world was founded on it. For Isaiah the prophet said, "Thus saith the Lord, 'Behold I lay in Zion a foundation for a stone...a costly corner-stone of sure foundation."' The Almighty, blessed be He, dropped a rock in the waters, and from thence the world expanded.
>
> > The Almighty created the world in the same manner as a child is formed in its mother's womb. Just as a child begins to grow from its navel and then develops into its full form, so the world began from its central point and then developed in all direction. (Ref. 2: Zev Vilnay, Legends of Jerusalem, The Jewish Publication Society of America, Philadelphia, 1973.)
>
> The Foundation Stone in known in Arabic es-Sakhra (and the Dome of the Rock, Kubbat es-Sakhra). On the western facade of the Dome of the Rock is the following Arabic inscription, The Rock of the Temple from the garden of Eden. The northern gate of the mosque facing the foundation stone is named the Gate of Paradise, Bab ej-Jinah. On the floor in front of this gate is a stone of green jasper about half a meter square called by the Arabs "the Stone of Eden."

For further information may be gleaned from the following sources:

- [Early Links between the the Temple and the Garden of Eden](https://www.academia.edu/7551509/Early_Links_between_the_the_Temple_and_the_Garden_of_Eden)
- [Where was Adam created? (Biblical Hermeneutics)](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/15659/where-was-adam-created)